# Scroll content outside of the modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-modal

I am using `react-native-modal` which only takes up part of the screen at the bottom I need to be able to **scroll content outside of the modal**. But all my clicks are on the backdrop of the modal window. Is there a way to do this?[image]

Comment: did you put hasBackdrop to false ?

Comment: yes, sure! hasBackdrop={false}